# Print the record count using Phoenix/Ecto from the terminal

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, elixir-mix

On the Rails app, we can print the record count of a database table by a command like this:

```
rails r "puts User.count"
```

With my knowledge, if we want the same thing on the Phoenix/Ecto environment, we should run such a command:

```
mix run -e "IO.puts SampleApp.Repo.aggregate(SampleApp.User, :count, :id)"
```

That is OK, but is too lengthy for a daily usage. Is there any shorter way?

Comment: unfortunately not. My solution would be to create an alias OR create a function for bash/zsh which shortens it for you

Comment: For getting info like this, especially if you need many different kinds of it, it's simpler to just use the db IDE, like pgAdmin or DataGrip and etc than getting all the info via terminal through mix, well at least in my opinion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Out of the box, there is not.**

You can however define a function in the `SampleApp` module to make it shorter. Something like this should do the trick (I haven't tested this):

```
defmodule SampleApp do
  ...

  def count(model)
    IO.puts Repo.aggregate(model, :count, :id)
  end
end
```

Then you can do this:

```
mix run -e "SampleApp.count(SampleApp.User)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file `db.count.ex` on the `lib/mix/tasks` directory as follows:

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Db.Count do
  use Mix.Task
  import Mix.Ecto

  @shortdoc "Print the row count of a database table"

  def run(args) do
    [repo|_] = parse_repo([])
    ensure_started(repo, [])

    app_name = Mix.Project.config[:app] |> Atom.to_string |> Macro.camelize
    model_name = List.first(args) |> Macro.camelize

    IO.puts repo.aggregate(Module.concat(app_name, model_name), :count, :id)
  end
end
```

Then you can get the row count of `LineItem` model:

```
mix db.count line_item
```

Note that the Mix task above assumes that the application has *single* repository (data store).